# How to properly program a button with JavaScript and html (very beginner)

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have been trying to program a very simple button using both Javascript and HTML yet it doesn't work even after trying to follow a tutorial. Im not sure what in my code is wrong and why its not working. here are some hopefully helpful images of my code
[Javascript Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duw4z.png)
[HTML image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3RYc.png)

Comment: The trouble is, images of code _aren't_ helpful. Please see [ask].

Comment: But the answer is that you have extra spaces in your attribute selector. It (presumably) doesn't look like that in the HTML, so it shouldn't in the JavaScript.

Comment: You should load your script *after* the button. Where you have it now it will not find the button, because it has not been parsed yet.

Comment: @trincot, the `defer` attribute on the script should resolve that.

Comment: I don't even see `button.js` being loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Next time please post your code, it would be a lot easier.

You have some extra spaces in the attribute of your `querySelector()` in the `button.js`.

It should look like this in line 1:

```
let button = document.querySelector('[data-button]');
```

Also you have to reference your script in the index.html. In line 8 of your screenshot of the `index.html` you have to write `button.js` instead of `script.js`.

```
 <script src="button.js" defer></script>
```

The complete code should look like in the following:

`index.html` :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="button.js" defer></script>
    <title>Button</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button data-button>button</button>
</body>

</html>
```

`button.js`:

```
let button = document.querySelector('[data-button]');

button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert("button clicked");
});
```